# Need to create Database on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to save data in a single table for later reference. The volume will not be more than 1000 per day and there will not be any joins. The DB will contain only single table.

I do not want to create on Amazon RDS as the cost is high for my corporation and also the connectivity between EC2 and RDS will require approvals and will take time.

I have root access, so is there a DB I can create on EC2 on any port which my web app running on port 80 can use?

Comment: Hi Romil, have you read about [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/)? It's a easy install and a lightweight document database with many languages integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the EC2 instance via SSH and install a mySQL database.

Guide for Ubuntu, but should work for Amazon Linux as well:

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/

However, if it is that low volume, you may want to check out DynamoDB. That may be a much more cost-effective (and easier to maintain) solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access and root permissions then you can install any community edition of databases.

- For an RDBMS, mysql can be an easier choice
- For a noSQL DB, mongoDB    is quite easy to setup